# Apache 2.4 Proxy to IIS server, wrongly looking in /var/www/html instead of C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Tags: iis, apache-2.4, proxy, iis-6, apache2

I have a config in Apache 2.4.6 on RHEL, to proxy requests to an IIS server v6.1 on Server2008R2 hosting the site. I can hit the service against IIS directly, so I know it's working. However, when I go through the proxy, I get a 404.

The following is in my sites-available directory (I had to scrub a lot of the data):

```
VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine on
    ServerName myserver
    ServerAlias myserver
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/myserver.domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/myserver.domain.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/CAs

    DocumentRoot C:\inetpub\wwwroot

    <Location "/TEST">
            SSLVerifyClient optional
            SSLVerifyDepth 5
            DocumentRoot C:\inetpub\wwwroot

            ProxyPass http://myserver.domain/TEST
            ProxyPassReverse http://myserver.domain/TEST
            Require all granted
            SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth
            SSLRequireSSL

            SSLRequire ( %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_C} eq "REMOVED" \
                    && %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_ST} eq "REMOVED" \
                    && %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_L} eq "REMOVED" \
                    && %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "REMOVED" \
                    && %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "REMOVED" \
                    && %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "REMOVED" )
    </Location>

    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyRequests Off

/VirtualHost>
```

The error in the logs is:
`AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/TEST`

Which tells me Apache is looking for the typical Linux directory, when I really want it to point to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. I've tried manually setting the DocumentRoot as shown above, changing the Location to all sort of variations on `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TEST`, I've tried making a `Directory` block which didn't work, changing the values for `ProxyPreserveHost Off` and `ProxyRequests Off`. Nothing is working. Is there some special directive to let Apache know it's talking to IIS?

Comment: are you trying to proxy the entire domain/site, or just a subpath of the site (with the rest still being served by Apache)?

Comment: @AnsonWHan - I am trying to proxy the whole thing. Apache in this case holds no content, it is just a passthru ... all of the site is being hosted on the IIS server.